# Link Facebook app to mobile website instead of Play Store listing

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, google-play

My Facebook app uses the Facebook Feed Dialog to post a story on the newsfeed. When anyone clicks a link in the message on their mobile device it directs the user to a page on our mobile website related to the story they posted which I set under mobile site URL in the Facebook developer settings.

However, I also have an Android app and if I fill in the details in the Facebook developer settings i.e. Package Name, Class name and Key Hashes when the user clicks on the link it now always goes to the Google Play store listing. I need to fill in these details so my app can be submitted to the Facebook app center.

How do I enforce that the link always go to my mobile website instead of Google Play store listing while keeping all my Android settings?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any luck?